# networks not available in RUN command in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I don't know how to ask better but I have 2 `docker-compose.yml` files in 2 separate directories. I've connected them with `networks external` and using service's name as hostname which works fine during runtime (`CMD node test.js`) but not working when I use `RUN node test.js` (I get `Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN backend` error while fetching with that address)

this is my code:

```yaml
# backend/docker-compose.yml

services:
    backend:
        container_name: backend
        networks:
          - my-network

networks:
    my-network:
```

```yaml
# front/docker-compose.yml

services:
    front:
        container_name: front
        build:
            context: .
            args:
              - BACKEND_URL=http://backend:1337
        networks:
          - backend_my-network
        depends_on:
          - backend

networks:
    backend_my-network:
        external: true
```

and this is how I build them:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Comment: In fact, Compose networks (even the `default` network) aren't available in the Dockerfile.  If running the tests doesn't have any effect on your final image, I'd just remove the `RUN node test.js` line from the Dockerfile; run the unit tests in your host development environment before building the image, or `docker-compose run front node test.js` to run integration tests after building.

Comment: @DavidMaze that `test.js` is a test file to check docker networking. actually I have a `NextJS` app which builds the app from Dockerfile (`RUN yarn build`) and then `CMD ["yarn", "start"]`. and during build time, `NextJS` needs the API for SSG contents. so there is no way to skip it :( (the `test.js` file just does some fetching to see if I can access to the API instead of spend a lot of time for nextjs getting build)

Comment: @DavidMaze I found `build.network` config on the document but not sure how to use it in my code. I tried by just adding `network: host` in `build` block but didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: @DavidMaze I got it work by adding `build.network: host` and rename `backend` to `localhost`. but do you think it is a good idea? won't it be a problem if want to build it on the server? or should I even build my apps on the server?!

Comment: What will happen if you build the image with host networking (where the hostname `localhost` reaches some server that happens to be running somewhere) but eventually launch the container with a different network setup (with a different server reachable via the host name `frontend`)?

Comment: @DavidMaze so, if I understood correctly, the `localhost` is actually the domain of the website (e.g `my-website.com`) and I have to replace it in production, right? sorry for my poor English